# System won't POST after BIOS upgrade (Asus z170-A)

Tags: bios, post, asus

After a "hard" power on (plugged in for first time) the "CPU" QLED stays lit and the device hangs.
If I reset it, the CPU check passes and the "Boot device" QLED stays lit, and the "American Megatrends" screen dumps me into the BIOS (I can't remember the exact wording, in essence "You've set something to a stupid value that is making the system unstable, fix it").
Closing the BIOS and triggering another reset goes back to the CPU failure state above. (Very occassionally it seems to stumble into a Win10 "Your boot device is unavailable" message.

The (2.5") SSD Boot device is detected in the BIOS, and at the top of the boot order.

The system was stable as of three days ago, with a GPU drawing extra power, but with the old BIOS version (I upgraded to try and get it to detect an M2 SSD).

Really I'm after things to try:
Can I force downgrade the BIOS?
How can I tell if I've knackered (or fix!) the boot device?

Things to note:

- I don't have a system speaker*
- I didn't save my BIOS settings before upgrading*
- I can't get the BIOS to downgrade - it says "Selected file is not a proper BIOS!"
- I have also spent ages building a windows recovery disk on an SD card in a reader - which a different laptop recognises but broken desktop BIOS doesn't "see" at all.
- I have tried wiping BIOS settings by shorting two pins (and by taking out the battery and shorting two pins) , it just sets the CPU fan to max and sits there like a brick, until I restart it again, then I'm back to the status above.

**System**

- Motherboard: ASUS Z170-A / BIOS was 0504, now 3802
- CPU: Core i5-6600
- RAM: Corsair-2666 DDR4, 2 * 4GB
- GPU: Removed - internal only
- PSU: Antec 650W

- Yes, I'm an idiot.

Comment: Try restarting in BIOS and set BIOS to default values. Restart and test.

Comment: There's been two days of faffing. I've _probably_ done that, but can't hurt to check... Back in a mo.

Comment: Got into the BIOS, F5 to set "Optimised defaults", save & exit --> Solid CPU LED, no POST
Reset, solid CPU LED
Reset, back to boot device LED & BIOS

Comment: It may be bricked. No fix for that except to replace.

Comment: If it’s getting to UEFI settings, then it’s not bricked (IMO), Windows attempting to boot is beyond the POST phase. It’s rare for motherboards to allow downgrading firmware.

Comment: Get the manual for the motherboard. check that you are doing the right procedure for a bios reset. reading up on uefi wouldnt hurt either

Comment: "Default" settings for some reason included overclocking, and running the RAM not at it's published frequency. Fixing both of those it booted into Windows recovery, when I noticed the log file was going to D:\Windows. So I then used diskpart to switch C (system recovery) and D, and make new C bootable. This was a mistake since it rendered the SSD completely unbootable. I've now acquired a USB stick, and built *another* windows recovery disk, and installed the M2 SSD. Next step is to install windows on the M2, then - of that works - slowly add components back.

Comment: *sigh* For the benefit of those that find this later. A windows "recovery drive" is distinct from Windows Installation media on a thumb drive - which has recovery tools on it. The former is *machine specific* and will not work on any other machine. The latter is what I needed.